# Documentdb return only 100 documents

Tags: mongodb, go, aws-documentdb

I understand that DocumentDB by default returns 100 documents if the 'size' parameter is not added, but I am sending a 'size' of 200 and it is only returning 100 documents. Is there any way to remove this limit?

```
session := dao.session.Copy()
defer session.Close()

pipeline := []bson.M{
    {
        matchOp: bson.M{
            "campaign": campaignID,
        },
    },
    {
        lookupOp: bson.M{
            "from":         contactsCollection,
            "localField":   "contactid",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as":           "contact",
        },
    },
    {
        unwindOp: contactAttribute,
    },
    {
        "$skip": offset,
    },
    {
        limitOp: pageSize,
    },
    {
        "$sort": bson.M{"_id": 1},
    },
}
var result []Test
err := session.DB(crmDB).C(dealsCollection).Pipe(pipeline).All(&result)
return result, err
```

Comment: `mgo` has not been maintained for _years_. Use the official `mongo-go` driver.